# Отрисовка движущейся синусоидной волны

Tags: c#, алгоритм, winforms, графика

Собственно как можно сделать таковую?

На Windows.Forms C#

Comment: Доброй ночи. Пробовал сделать по примеру подобного видео? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UAEFMvRaZ3M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функцию можно нарисовать линиями: задаем шаг рисования s и проводим линии (x, f(x), x+s, f(x+s)).

Эффект движущейся функции можно сделать смещением всего графика вправо.

Сделал через объект Graphics, поэтому работает не очень быстро.
Получилось около 100 строчек кода, чтоб не спамить, даю [ссылку](https://github.com/miptleha/forms_movefunc/blob/main/Form1.cs) на код.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляю код в текст ответа:

1. Смещение функции вправо:

```cs
for (double shift = 0; ; shift += .05)
{
  DrawF(g, Math.Sin, 100, 100 * Math.PI, shift);
}
```

2. Построение функции отрезками:

```cs
void DrawF(Graphics g, Func<double, double> f, double XSCALE, double YSCALE, double xShift)
{
  double XCENTER = this.Width / 2;
  double YCENTER = this.Height / 2;
  double XSIZE = this.Width;

  double xStart = -XCENTER / XSCALE - xShift;
  double xEnd = (XSIZE - XCENTER) / XSCALE;
  double XSTEP = .05;

  double x1 = xStart;
  double y1 = -f(x1);
  Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1);
  for (double x = xStart + XSTEP; x < xEnd + XSTEP; x += XSTEP)
  {
    double y = -f(x);
    g.DrawLine(pen, (int)((x1 + xShift) * XSCALE + XCENTER), (int)(y1 * YSCALE + YCENTER), (int)((x + xShift) * XSCALE + XCENTER), (int)(y * YSCALE + YCENTER));
    x1 = x;
    y1 = y;
  }
}
```

полный код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var g = this.CreateGraphics())
            {
                //use buffering to avoid blinking
                Bitmap buffer = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
                Graphics g1 = Graphics.FromImage(buffer);
                g1.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;

                for (double shift = 0; ; shift += .05)
                {
                    g1.Clear(this.BackColor);
                    DrawF(g1, Math.Sin, 100, 100 * Math.PI, shift); //shift right

                    try
                    {
                        g.DrawImage(buffer, new Point(0, 0));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        //form was closed
                    }
                    await Task.Delay(1); //do not block user interface
                }
            }
        }

        //draw an arbitrary function
        private void DrawF(Graphics g, Func<double, double> f, double XSCALE, double YSCALE, double xShift)
        {
            //how many pixels in interval [0, 1]
            //double XSCALE = 100;
            //double YSCALE = Math.PI * XSCALE;

            //position of (0,0) coordinate
            double XCENTER = this.Width / 2;
            double YCENTER = this.Height / 2;

            //drawing area
            double XSIZE = this.Width;
            double YSIZE = this.Height;

            Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1);

            //show axes
            g.DrawLine(pen, 0, (int)YCENTER, (int)XSIZE, (int)YCENTER);
            g.DrawLine(pen, (int)XCENTER, 0, (int)XCENTER, (int)YSIZE);
            DrawString(g, "0", (int)XCENTER, (int)YCENTER);

            //axis marks
            double DASH = 10; //mark size
            for (int i = 1; XCENTER + i * XSCALE < XSIZE; i++)
            {
                g.DrawLine(pen, (int)(XCENTER + i * XSCALE), (int)(-DASH / 2 + YCENTER), (int)(XCENTER + i * XSCALE), (int)(DASH / 2 + YCENTER));
                DrawString(g, i.ToString(), (int)(XCENTER + i * XSCALE), (int)YCENTER);
            }
            for (int i = -1; XCENTER + i * XSCALE > 0; i--)
            {
                g.DrawLine(pen, (int)(XCENTER + i * XSCALE), (int)(-DASH / 2 + YCENTER), (int)(XCENTER + i * XSCALE), (int)(DASH / 2 + YCENTER));
                DrawString(g, i.ToString(), (int)(XCENTER + i * XSCALE), (int)YCENTER);
            }
            for (int i = -1; YCENTER + i * YSCALE > 0; i--)
            {
                g.DrawLine(pen, (int)(-DASH / 2 + XCENTER), (int)(YCENTER + i * YSCALE), (int)(DASH / 2 + XCENTER), (int)(YCENTER + i * YSCALE));
                DrawString(g, (-i).ToString(), (int)XCENTER, (int)(YCENTER + i * YSCALE));
            }
            for (int i = 1; YCENTER + i * YSCALE < YSIZE; i++)
            {
                g.DrawLine(pen, (int)(-DASH / 2 + XCENTER), (int)(YCENTER + i * YSCALE), (int)(DASH / 2 + XCENTER), (int)(YCENTER + i * YSCALE));
                DrawString(g, (-i).ToString(), (int)XCENTER, (int)(YCENTER + i * YSCALE));
            }

            //draw funtion with lines: f(x) -> f(x + XSTEP)
            double xStart = -XCENTER / XSCALE - xShift;
            double xEnd = (XSIZE - XCENTER) / XSCALE;
            double XSTEP = .05; //x step
            bool isFirst = true;
            double x1 = 0, y1 = 0; //previous point
            for (double x = xStart; x < xEnd + XSTEP; x += XSTEP)
            {
                double y = -f(x); //mirror y coordinate
                if (double.IsNaN(y))
                    continue;
                if (!isFirst)
                    g.DrawLine(pen, (int)((x1 + xShift) * XSCALE + XCENTER), (int)(y1 * YSCALE + YCENTER), (int)((x + xShift) * XSCALE + XCENTER), (int)(y * YSCALE + YCENTER));
                x1 = x;
                y1 = y;
                isFirst = false;
            }
        }

        //show a text at specific coordinate
        private void DrawString(Graphics g, string str, int x, int y)
        {
            SizeF a = TextRenderer.MeasureText(str, this.Font);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(g, str, this.Font, new Point(x, y), Color.Black);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Код надо приводить прямо в ответе, потому что как только протухнет ссылка на код, этот ответ превратится в тыкву. Максимальная длина ответа 30000 знаков. 2 таких кода влезут.